# Finding the current through an inductor in a second order circuit?

Tags: parallel, passive-networks, equation

[image]

Assume that the circuit has reached a steady state. I'm trying to find the current through the inductor at some time, t, which should be a function of t.

I'm having trouble creating a system of equations for each branch. So far, I've using a KCL at the node before R1, and tried creating a few equations to determine a second order equation for the current through the inductor. I just can't figure out where to go next, or if I am doing this right at all. To be clear, I am trying to find the solution to a second order differential equation for the current through the inductor, which should be a function of time.

Here is what I've written down. I'm really not sure where to go from here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEVhf.jpg

edit: I was able to solve this using a Laplace transform, but for the purposes of learning how to do this in different ways, and to prepare for exams, I'm trying to learn how to do it in such a way that utilizes a system of equations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write KVL for each branch:
$$V_b = i_LR_2+L\frac{di_L}{dt}$$
$$V_b = i_cR_1+\frac{1}{C}\int_{-\infty}^ti_Cdt$$
Differentiate both the equations and use \$i_c = I-i_L\$ (KCL at node b):
$$\frac{dV_b}{dt} = R_2\frac{di_L}{dt}+L\frac{d^2i_L}{dt^2}$$
$$\frac{dV_b}{dt} = -\frac{di_L}{dt}R_1+\frac{I-i_L}{C}$$
Eliminate \$V_b\$ and some rearrangement:
$$LC\frac{d^2i_L}{dt^2}+(R_1+R_2)C\frac{di_L}{dt}+i_L = I$$
You can then solve this equation.

Answer (score 2):

You might have an easier time reaching the solution if you try KVL on the circuit.
[image: Edited circuit with recommended loop analysis]

Immediately we can conclude that I1=Is therefore we only need to write down the second loop.

$$
I_2: \quad V_{R_2}+V_L-V_C-V_{R_1}=0
$$
$$
I_2=I
$$

Knowing this, we express the inductor voltage as a derivative and the capacitor voltage as an integral, resulting in the desired second order equation you were looking for.

Comment: `Immediately we can conclude that I1=Is` how?

Comment: I agree with the commenter above. I1 = Is for the initial condition of current through the capacitor, but not for the overall response of the circuit, right? Not sure if it's because I wasn't clear in my question, but I'm trying to find the transient response of the current through the inductor.

Comment: I1=Is for ever and ever t>0 simply because the mesh current I1 flows through the constant current generator. It's very basic mesh analysis. Don't confuse mesh current I1 and capacitor current which is I1-I2 instead

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that we can use the [current divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider) formula in the (complex) s-domain (using [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

$$\text{i}_\text{L}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_2+\text{sL}}\cdot\text{i}_\text{s}\left(\text{s}\right)\tag1$$

Using the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the Laplace transform we can write (in the time domain):

$$\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_2+\text{sL}}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{i}_\text{s}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau=$$
$$\int_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_2+\text{sL}}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\cdot\text{I}_\text{s}\left(\tau\right)\space\text{d}\tau\tag2$$

Using Mathematica I found that the inverse Laplace transform is given by:

[image]

Comment: The OP said they already had solved the problem using Laplace. They asked for help finding the differential equations.